# how can i pass javascript cookies to php cookies?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I want to create and save html code into file, so i want to use PHP to create file. 
Now, I have a problem that i can pass Javascript cookies containing html code to php cookies.
How can I solve it? Thanks.

```
function save()
     {
        fcookie='testing';
        var test = $("body").html();
        document.cookie=fcookie+"=" + test;
     }  


<?php
  if (isset($_COOKIE["testing"]);
  $file_name = 'index.php';

  fopen($file_name, "w");
  file_put_contents($file_name, $_COOKIE["testing"]);

  ?>
```

Comment: Solve it by not passing it through a cookie.. Why would you try do it that way? this is what forms and the `POST` method are for..

Comment: I dont think that is possible. As Darren mentioned, we should try doing a POST.

Comment: what you want to achieve by doing that?

Comment: using `fopen()` but not assigning to a variable?

Comment: Using the combination of `fopen` and `file_put_contents` doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Solution via cookies is in my answer below - but else I agree with @Darren that usage of cookies is not good idea in this case. And by the way, you inspired me to make what I wanted to make some time (even if I have not usage for it).

Comment: What have you done to try to debug the problem? Have you looked at the JavaScript console? Have you looked at the Net tab of your browser's developer tools? Can you see the request and response? Are they are you expect? Does the cookie appear in the request header? Do you actually get a POST request?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of the cookie to the content of the body element. This is very likely to include characters (such as new lines) which will break the cookie.

NB: Replacing `test` with `"foo"` produces working code while `\nfoo"` does not.

You must encode the data to remove any characters which have special meaning or are forbidden. The approach [MDN uses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) is to pass the data through `encodeURIComponent` when generating your cookie string.

```
document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(fcookie) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(test);
```

Note that HTML documents are often quite long, so you may also exceed the length limits on cookies by including that amount of data in one.